# tensorboard ModuleNotFoundError when initialising function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

Even though Ive tried to initialise Tensorboard several ways - `from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard` , `from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard` , atd. when initialising right before model.fit function I always get ModuleNotFoundError or similar.

I've tried several different directories for Tensorboard logs, several ways to initialize via Keras layer

```
import tensorflow as tf
#sess = tf.Session()
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
# more info on callbakcs: https://keras.io/callbacks/ model saver is cool too.
#from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pickle
import time

NAME = "Cats-vs-dogs-CNN"

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              )

tensor_board = TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)

model.fit(X, y,
          batch_size=16,
          epochs=1,
          validation_split=0.3,
          callbacks=[tensor_board])
```

Its based on tutorial https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorboard-analysis-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/?completed=/convolutional-neural-network-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/
Original code was written like this:

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              )

model.fit(X, y,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=10,
          validation_split=0.3,
          callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

But I was getting an error that callbacks=[tensorboard]) is not found so I've kinda deducted it is because I use Tensorflow2.0 and this is based on r1 version.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,

You have to use

```
  tensorflow.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard
```

you are using directly keras api, like you try to use two different APIs.

Please try to follow the documentation of tf 2.0 api, it works well.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/get_started

Comment: Hi Yassine, I have tried that already, I have left it there commented, so it shows I have tried it and doesnt work :/